# How to Print Photo from Android Device using Printershare Application or any other application?

Tags: android

How to Print Photo or Document from Android Device using Printershare Application or any other application?

Comment: Check these links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726168/print-image-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383435/how-to-open-printershare-application-in-android-from-my-current-application