# How to open PrinterShare application in android from my current application

Tags: android, android-intent

As I am developing an android app, I came across the need of launching the PrinterShare app installed on my android phone. I want that when user hits the `Button` control in my app, it should launch the PrinterShare app. When user is done with the document which he/she needs to print, then it should come back to home application, from when it was launched.

Any idea, code snippet would be appreciated.
Thanks.. :-)

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html

Comment: http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.dynamixsoftware.printershare

Comment: @nik: I've already installed PrinterShare on my emulator. Now I want to launch it to print a txt file which I make generated in my application context. As the task of PrinterShare finishes, it should come back to the parent application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lately but fortunately I got the answer. 
Here it is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
i.setDataAndType(printFileUri,"text/plain");
startActivity(i);
```

where 'printFileUri' is as follows:

```
static final Uri printFileUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Calci_print.txt");
```

If anyone has still another suggestion, its most welcomed.. :-)

Comment: This did not work for me.  I get an `ActivityNotFoundException` when I do this.

Comment: Have you installed the PrintShare application on your device/emulator? Also don't forget to add in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

If you receive an ActivityNotFoundException, take a look at the actual name of the installed package (pm command from Android console). In my case I found that the copy I bought from the Amazon App Store had a package name of *`com.dynamixsoftware.printershare.amazon`*.

Given that my users might obtain the PrinterShare app from Google, I actually check the package manager for the first package name *beginning* with *com.dynamixsoftware.printershare*.