# Intent unable to handle PrinterShare

Tags: android, printing

My code

```
 public boolean queuePictureStreamForPrinting( Bitmap bMap )
{
    Log.e( TAG, "Printing in queue");
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/PrintFolder/");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/www/images");
    //uri = Uri.fromFile( bMap );
    Intent i = new Intent(PRINT_ACTION  );
    i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
    i.setDataAndType( uri, "application/x-android-picture-stream" );
    i.putExtra( "scaleFitToPage", true );
    startActivity( i );

    return true;
}
```

When i pass the function, it gives me an error that says

```
 01-06 16:38:12.647: E/AndroidRuntime(343): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare.print dat=file:///android_asset/www/images typ=application/x-android-picture-stream pkg=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare (has extras) }**
```

what am i doing wrong?

```
<activity android:name=".PrintUtils" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <grant-uri-permission android:path="com.dynamixsoftware.printershare" android:pathPattern="string" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Didn't you asked that yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726168/print-image-in-android

Comment: yes. But after making a lot of changes, I was getting different sets of errors and now am back to square 1.

Comment: So the fix didn't help you anymore? Have you register the intent in your manifest?

Comment: <activity android:name=".PrintUtils" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
   
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <grant-uri-permission 
          android:path="com.dynamixsoftware.printershare"
                      android:pathPattern="string"
                 />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>

Comment: @warren: thats how i have registered it in manifest.

Comment: does your `PRINT_ACTION` matches the `ACTION_VIEW`?

Comment: @warren: what exactly do you mean? how is it supposed to match?

Comment: i want to print a html file that is diplayed in webview and i used-Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare"); //String path="file:///" + base_url+ "/Pages/"; i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(getdata(htmlpagepath)), "text/html"); startActivity(i); but showing activity not found